# How does function getline know newline character there

Tags: c++

I am curious about principle behind getline function defined in header `string`, if cin >> operator will never set second operand have any newline character, how does getline work, how does it know it's a new line there?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean with `if cin >> operator will never set second operand have any newline character`.

Comment: cin never tell us where have newline, so how does getline know?

Comment: An `istream` has a [get](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) function to read each char individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getline` uses [istream::get()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/) to read one character at a time in a loop. It's then easy for `getline` to check if the character just read is a newline and break out of the loop.

`getline` doesn't use `operator>>`.